# How to add to an SKAction sequence a function which returns a void?

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I am adding a particle emitter to an SKSpriteNode object (a ball) to make a trail as it moves. The following code returns the ball to its original location:

```
let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: origNP.x, y: origNP.y), duration: 0.3)
let doneTrail: Void = moveThis.removeAllChildren()
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, doneTrail])
moveThis.run(sequence)
```

My goal being that I don't want to remove the emitter till the ball is back in its original spot. However the above code doesn't work because I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected element type
> 'SKAction'

So the way I do it now is:

```
let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: origNP.x, y: origNP.y), duration: 0.3)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction])
moveThis.run(sequence)
moveThis.removeAllChildren()
```

But obviously the trail disappears before the ball is returned.

Is there a way to add a void returning method to an SKAction sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to turn a piece of code into an `SKAction`, so that you can put it into a sequence (or whatever other thing you want to do with it), you can use [`SKAction.run`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417692-run):

```
let doneTrail = SKAction.run { moveThis.removeAllChildren() }
```

Now that `doneTrail` is an `SKAction`, `SKAction.sequence([moveAction, doneTrail])` should compile.